# How to change the layout of category page when user logged in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, template, xml, frontend

I want to change category layout when user/customer successfully logged in. I had a normal category page with 2 column layout for public user(not login) and I want to change into 1 column when user logged in.

Comment: `magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Controller\Category\View.php` Orverirde this file `if ($settings->getPageLayout()) {
                $page->getConfig()->setPageLayout($settings->getPageLayout());
            }` check Login & Logout & Set

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, but i tried to print_r $setting->getPageLayout() but it return nothing. what is the output of $setting->getPageLayout? because all i want is to change the xml layout. i have  2 xml layout, for login and not login. how can i set the layout on that controller when user login or not?

Answer (score 1):

Very often question. You can try to use this [module](http://frankclark.xyz/modules/magento-2-get-customer_logged_in-and-customer_logged_out-layout-handles) 
to support CUSTOMER_LOGGED_IN handle in your xml files for different layouts